# MVC 3 How to make a form with Post Redirect Get method while maintaining views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, post-redirect-get

I've read a LOT on Stack and read a few articles else where on how to design a proper form. I ended up adopting the PRG method. [article here](http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201104/Blog/ASP-NET-MVC-Post-Redirect-Get-Pattern/)

The problem I'm having is actually getting it to work in IE 8. It sort of works in Firefox. I just want to know what I'm doing wrong.

**Update**

The Form validation is now fixed thanks to trial and error. Validation scripts with IE DO NOT work with Jquery 1.7. They do work with Jquery 1.5 as they are suppose to.

**Edit**
The form validations also don't work in IE with this current setup. Any light into this would be appreciated.

**Problems**

1.The Create View is actually loaded as a partial view which is inside the Index view. Picture a popup to add a new Subscriber.

So when the form submits and it's invalid, it goes to the partial view Create which now looks ridiculous because the partial view was meant to be a popup not a page.

How can I fix this so the pop stays up if it's invalid, instead of posting back to the Create View?

Should I just forget about popups and do a new page for forms? What's the best practice and most practical solution to PRG and forms?

The structure I have setup looks like this:

**Model**

```
 public class Subscribers
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Name is required")]
        [Display(Name = "Subscriber Name: ")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = " URI is required")]
        [Display(Name = "URI (email or url): ")]
        public string URI { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Channel: ")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = " Channel is required")]
        public int SelectedChannelID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Subscriber Type: ")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = " Type is required")]
        public int? SelectedSubscriberTypeID { get; set; }

        public List<Models.Subscriber> getSubscribers()
        {

            Models.SwitchboardEntities db = new Models.SwitchboardEntities();
            List<Models.Subscriber> subscriberList = db.Subscribers.ToList();

            return subscriberList;
        }
```

**View**

Create.cshmtl

```
@model Switchboard.Models.Subscribers      
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    @using (@Html.BeginForm("Create", "Subscriber", Model, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "addForm" }))
    {
    <fieldset>
    <legend><h3>Create</h3></legend>

    <br />
     @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
     <div class="editor-fields">
           @Html.LabelFor(xModels => xModels.Name)
           @Html.EditorFor(xModels => xModels.Name)
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(xModels => xModels.Name)
     </div>
     <div class="editor-fields">
           @Html.LabelFor(xModels => xModels.URI)
           @Html.EditorFor(xModels => xModels.URI)
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(xModels => xModels.URI)
     </div>
}
```

...

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Models.Subscribers model)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add insert logic here
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                else
                {
                    return View(model);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return View(model);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I can assure you, jquery validation works just fine in IE8 with jquery 1.7.  There is clearly something you are doing that is making IE get confused.

Comment: @Mystere Man well please enlighten me because "clearly something I'm doing" isn't so clear...since it works with 1.5 and not 1.7 and I haven't changed anything else in my code then I'm just making logical deductions. I'd be more than happy to take any suggestions you have for me :)

Comment: All too often people say "It works when i do this, but not when I do that, so there must be something wrong with it" when in reality,the problem is somewhere else, it's just showing up when you do that thing.  A lot of times, the code should have never worked in the first case, but for some lucky reason it did, even though it was wrong. You see this a lot when a new version of an OS comes out. Someones code breaks, and they blame the new OS, when in reality their code is broken and it just happened to work in the old version by accident. My point is you're making assumptions, not deductions.

Comment: Good point, I agree. But my point is I'm not getting suggestions or constructive feedback. Just pointing out my assumptions are wrong doesn't point me in the right direction. I'm obviously here to ask a community of experts who "see" something I don't. So I made an assumption and you pointed it out, now what? Cool story.

Comment: I gave you suggestions in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

There are many things you're not doing quite right.  First, jQuery should be loaded in your layout file (in the head section), not in your partial view (I assume Create.cshtml is partial).  jQuery needs to be loaded as early as possible (and should be the first script you load), and it should be loaded before the page is rendered.  By putting it so far in, you are just asking for trouble.

I would also load the jquery.validation and jquery.validation.unobtrusive in the layout as well.

If you can do so, i'd download the MVC4 beta, and generate a default internet application.  The MVC4 default app uses a popup login dialog, that includes validation and does not go away if the validation fails.. exactly what you're looking for.  You should be able to adapt their code to your own needs.

Also, make sure you have the latest versions of jQuery.validation, and jQuery.validation.unobtrusive.  Use NuGet to retrieve the latest versions of everything.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to store the data in the `TempData` object available to both the controller and the view (if needed) and then extract it and use it if its there on the next request.

#### Controller

```
public ActionResult Create(Models.Subscribers model) {
  // .. snip ..
  if (ModelState.IsValid) {
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
  // .. snip ..
  this.TempData["SubscribersTemp"] = model;
  this.RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

This stores the model in the `TempData` object for the next request and sends the user back to the Index action. This action can do its normal routine and once it hits the `@Html.RenderAction("RenderCreate")` line, the new logic will grab the temp data and send it to the view.

```
public PartialViewResult RenderCreate() { // use name of partial view here
  // The next line will use the model from the TempData if it exists or
  // create a new, empty model if it does not.

  // Using the create method above as an example, if the model is valid,
  // the next line will create a new subscribers object to pass to the partial
  // view. If it was invalid, it'll use the object stored in TempData instead.
  Models.Subscribers model = 
      this.TempData["SubscribersTemp"] as Model.Subscribers ??
      new Model.Subscribers();

  return this.View(model);
}
```

The `TempData` object will persist the data for the **next request** only. Once that request is complete, the `TempData` object is cleaned.

Comment: What does the Create method return if my ModelState is Invalid?

Comment: oh nvm I think you meant to write `return this.redirectoaction...`

Comment: I really wanted to stay on the Popup when the model was invalid. If the popup closes and returns to Index then they have to reload the RenderCreate form. Did I misunderstand your solution?

Comment: Depending on how your popup works, you can cause it to pop back up with the information. If it's in javascript, just add some logic on the document ready event (assuming jQuery) and add something like `@if (Model != null) {<text>$("#popup").dialog("show");</text>}`. (The <text> tags are to tell razor that the text inside the if statement isn't additional razor code but actual text (in this case, javascript) to be rendered to the page.)

Comment: Nice solution for the popup :). But I'm still not able to make this work with IE 8. My form validations aren't working anymore.

Comment: @MystereMan so if the user submits and it stores the data via some code it's all gone somehow by a refresh? Could you please elaborate Mystere? Merci